# Are there prayers or blessings for craftspeople to recite before making objects?

Tags: blessing, art

I'm interested in any relevant information/rites on this subject that reflect

- intentions for success
- gratitude for skill or aptitude or having an able body (ESPECIALLY
  interested in this)
- blessings over completed works
- rituals for making general daily items
- rituals for making specific liturgical objects (mezuzah, tefillot,
  etc)

Answer (score 1):

In general we only make blessing on commandments. Since there are no commandments to make physical objects (except for *sifrei Torah, mezuzot, tfilin*), I am not aware of such blessings before making objects.

However a Jew recites blessings every morning to thank God for keeping him alive, giving him a functioning body, eyes to see, legs to walk, being healthy, etc.

Some examples from the morning prayer service

> I offer thanks to You, living and eternal King, for You have
>   mercifully restored my soul within me; Your faithfulness is great.
>
> Praised are You, Lord our God King of the universe, who with wisdom
>   fashioned the human body, creating openings, arteries, glands and
>   organs, marvelous in structure, intricate in design. Should but one of
>   them, by being blocked or opened, fail to function, it would be
>   impossible to exist. Praised are you, Lord, healer of all flesh who
>   sustains our bodies in wondrous ways.
>
> Praised are You, Lord our God King of the universe, who with wisdom
>   fashioned the human body, creating openings, arteries, glands and
>   organs, marvelous in structure, intricate in design. Should but one of
>   them, by being blocked or opened, fail to function, it would be
>   impossible to exist. Praised are you, Lord, healer of all flesh who
>   sustains our bodies in wondrous ways.
>
> Blessed are you, Hashem, our G-d and king of the world, who opens [the
>   eyes of] the blind.
>
> Blessed are you, Hashem, our G-d and king of the world, who
>   straightens the bent.

The laws of writing holy texts on parchments (*tefilin, mezuzot, sefer Torah*) are complex. There is no specific blessing on the object but a scribe writing a mezuzah will make a declaration that he is doing it for the sake of the holiness of the mezuzah (see e.g., [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/312461/jewish/The-Laws-and-Customs.htm)) and not just writing for the sake of it.